# Setting up a deferred/promise across different obj properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

using jquery 1.6.*

I am using a module'ish pattern. I want to be able to create and resolve deffereds in my 'UNI.obj1" and be able to use them so I can initiate behavior in my "UNI.obj2" object.

Lets say I have the following object:

```
var UNI = {};

UNI.obj1 = function() {
    // set up a deferred here;

    var method1 = function(){
       // RESOLVE deferred here

    }
    var method1A = function(){
        window.onload = function(){ 
            method1(); 
        }
    }()
}()

UNI.obj2 = function(o) {
    var method2 = function(){
       // Use the PROMISE of the resolve here

    }
}(UNI.obj1);
```

Comment: I would suggest upgrading to jQuery 1.8+ if you want to use jQuery deferred objects.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on your code? as it is, it's relatively useless because method2 and method1 are never executed and can't be executed. I'd prefer to see how you would use the code rather than try to mangle it myself to make it execute.

Comment: I think you should start of with plain object literals and convert them to modules later on if you find it necessary, rather than making something in between. Can you provide a use case of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Kevin -- Lets assume those methods are executable at some point. Lets assume they are called. I mean, the skeleton of what I need is there, but I think "when" those methods are called are not that important. Lets assume they are called at appropriate times. Deferreds are available in my version of jquery

Comment: Right... give me an example of how it would be executed so that i can execute it  the way you would execute it. Right now i can't test your code without making significant changes to it.

Comment: My point about jquery 1.6 vs 1.8 is that jQuery deferreds are very different in 1.8 vs 1.6. (though, i don't think that will affect your use-case until you start to use `.then`)

Comment: ok, basically when the window is loaded, i want to set up a deferred. Since I will be doing some other stuff, I call method1A immediately self invoking, then call method1 on window.onload. Will that suffice in what you need?

Comment: kinda. I'm going to assume you're generating the deferred object outside of `method1` and returning it from `obj1()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your deferred object and return it's promise, then act upon it.

```
var UNI = {};

UNI.obj1 = function () {
    // set up a deferred here;
    var def = $.Deferred();

    var method1 = function () {
        // RESOLVE deferred here
        def.resolve();

        return def.promise();
    }
    var method1A = function () {
        window.onload = function () {
            method1();
        }
    }()
    return def.promise();
}

UNI.obj2 = function (o) {
    var method2 = function () {
        // Use the PROMISE of the resolve here
        o().done(function () {
            // it was resolved!
            console.log("Resolved!");
        });
    }()
}(UNI.obj1);
```

Comment: I find the `var foo = function () {}()` hard to follow. It doesn't really make sense because you end up with `foo` equaling `undefined` unless `foo` returned something. `method1A` for example is undefined. That mightaswell have instead been an iife. `(function(){}())`

Answer (score 1):

```
var UNI = {};

UNI.obj1 = function() {
    // set up a deferred here;
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    var method1 = function(){
       // RESOLVE deferred here
       deferred.resolve('something')
    }
}

UNI.obj2 = function(o) {
    var method2 = function(promise){
       // Use the PROMISE of the DEFERRED? here
       // pass promise
    }
}
```

But I don't see in your question how you want to pass the deferred object, since you said you want module pattern, you could:

```
UNI.obj1 = function() {
    // set up a deferred here;
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();

    var method1 = function(){
       // RESOLVE deferred here
       deferred.resolve('something')
    }

    // module pattern
    return {
      promise: deferred.promise()
    };
    // you could also just return the promise, maybe I am misunderstanding your question
    // return deferred.promise();
}

UNI.obj2 = function(o) {
    var method2 = function(promise){
       // Use the PROMISE of the DEFERRED? here
       // pass promise
    }

    // module pattern
    return {method2: method2};
}


// Usage
var o1 = UNI.obj1();
var o2 = UNI.obj2();
o2.method2(o1.promise);
```